# Basic security not kicking in with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm trying to setup a vanilla Spring Boot environment with Basic authentication.

Basically the only thing I want to customize are the users, the protected paths and a custom password encoder.

The Spring Boot documentation states:

> To override the access rules without changing any other autoconfigured
>   features add a @Bean of type WebConfigurerAdapter with
>   @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER).

Note: I think WebConfigurerAdapter should be WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

So I tried the following:

```
protected static class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/management/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .withUser("admin")
                    .password(passwordEncoder.encode("pwd"))
                    .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .withUser("user")
                    .password(passwordEncoder.encode("pwd"))
                    .roles("USER");
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

The default Boot security seem exactly what I want:

```
security.enable-csrf=false
security.basic.enabled=true 
security.sessions=stateless
```

However when I run the app the Basic Authentication does not work.

When I configure it explicitly in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter using `http.httpBasic()` like:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/management/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

Then the Basic Authentication is working.

So the initial setup above does not seem to take the default configuration.

Am I missing something?

Comment: But your example doesn't use `@Order`...

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5046

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `WebSecurityConfigurer` has its own filter chain with its own request matchers and security rules. Adding a `WebSecurityConfigurer` (sorry for the typo in the docs) doesn't change the default boot autoconfig filter chain but it doesn't do anything magic for its own filter chain either. You need to tell Spring Security how to secure those resources - you gave it access rules but no authentication strategy. Makes sense?

Comment: OK, security in Spring boot is sometimes like black magic :-) Anyway if I just want to override the access rules. Should I setup it different then? The docs seems to suggest that there is a way to use Boot default security setup and just override the access rules. (see quote from docs in top of post).

Comment: What you are doing is fine, and makes total sense to me. I thought you said it worked when you add the `httpBasic()`?

Comment: Yes after adding httpBasic() it works fine. But by default Security in Boot has this already set. That's why it seems to me it's not taking the defaults... without adding httpBasic() - and even with security.basic.enabled=true - it does not work.

Comment: Thats why I think the statement from the docs "To override the access rules without changing any other autoconfigured features add a @Bean of type WebConfigurerAdapter with @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)." is misleading. When I do this and only set access rules the default enable http security does not work anymore.